# How to detect single.php (but not single-portfolio.php)?

Tags: posts, functions, single

When I'm using `is_single();` in my `<head>` section to add some style to website navigation it executes correctly on blog posts but it also executes on single "portfolio" post type posts (so single-portfolio.php and single.php).

How do I make it execute only on single.php?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the following instead,

```
if (is_singular('post')) {

    //your code here...

}
```

Where by `is_singular` is the WordPress API conditional function for testing for the existence of a post type. You can also pass an array of post types if you wish.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Comment: That's another very good answer! Both answers resolve this issue. This one seems to be simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, always best to use built-in functions. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) :

to check if it's not a specific post-type :

```
if ( is_single() && 'portfolio' != get_post_type() ) {
  // DO STUFF
}
```

or to check if it's a post and not a post-type :

```
if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
  // DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That resolves my problem BUT what if I have "slideshow", "news", "portfolio" and a lot more post types? Some can be extended using plugins and I'm not sure how many there will be and what will be their names. Is there a way to do it without excluding just "portfolio" but everything that is not a blog post?

Comment: @Flow: use `get_post_type()` to check for `'post'`.

Comment: I have updated my answer ^^